# $\vec{p}\times\vec{r}=\vec{q}+c\vec{p}$ and $\vec{p}.\vec{r}=2$.Find the vector $\vec{r}$ and the value of $c$.

Tags: vectors

Consider three vectors $\vec{p},\vec{q},\vec{r}$ such that 
$\vec{p}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k};\vec{q}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}+\hat{k}$
$\vec{p}\times\vec{r}=\vec{q}+c\vec{p}$ and $\vec{p}.\vec{r}=2$.Find the vector $\vec{r}$ and the value of $c$.

---

My Attempt:
As $\vec{p}\times\vec{r}=\vec{q}+c\vec{p}$,so $\vec{r}$ must be in the perpendicular to both $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$.So let $\vec{r}=\lambda( \vec{p}\times\vec{q})$
I calculated $\vec{r}=\lambda(2\hat{i}-2\hat{k})=2\lambda\hat{i}-2\lambda\hat{k}$
But $\vec{p}.\vec{r}$ comes out to be $0$ and not $2$,as given in one of the conditions.What is wrong in this approach?

---

My Second try:
As $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ are non-collinear vectors,So
Let $\vec{r}=x\vec{p}+y\vec{q}+z\vec{p}\times\vec{q}$
$\vec{r}=(x+y+2z)\hat{i}+(x-y)\hat{j}+(x+y-2z)\hat{k}$
But i could not solve it further.Please help me.

Comment: Try  $(\vec{p} \times \vec{r}). \vec{r}$  and $(\vec{p} \times \vec{r}). \vec{p}$  and see the results .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty straightforward to me: $$ \vec p=(1,1,1) ,  \vec q=(1,-1,1)$$
$$\vec p \times \vec r=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\
      r_{a}&r_{b}&r_{c}
    \end{array}
\right]=(r_{c}-r_{b})\hat i+(r_{a}-r_{c})\hat j+(r_{b}-r_{a})\hat k $$
$$\vec q+c\vec p=(1+c,-1+c,1+c)$$
$$r_{c}-r_{b}=1+c ,r_{a}-r_{c}=-1+c,r_{b}-r_{a}=1+c$$
$$\vec r.\vec p= r_{a}+ r_{b}+r_{c}=2$$

Then you solve the above system which gives you $$\vec r=(0,2/3,4/3), c=-1/3$$